# Access checkbox value of an item in an array - Sitecore

Tags: html, razor, sitecore

I cannot seem to get the value of a checkbox field of "NoIndexNoFollow" I have set in my content.

I have tried two of the follow code samples below.

1) I get FALSE for every item even if I check the box in the content editor.

```
foreach (var item in Model.SiteSearchResults)
{
Sitecore.Data.Fields.CheckboxField checkboxField = Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["NoIndexNoFollow"];
if (checkboxField.Checked)
{ *CODE*}
}
```

2) Nothing populates here.

```
foreach (var item in Model.SiteSearchResults)
{
var toindex = Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["NoIndexNoFollow"].ToString();
if (toindex == "1")
{ *CODE* }
}
```

I am getting no value from these items.....Not sure the right way to call a checkbox field even though either of these seem to be working for other examples I am looking at.

Comment: What is the type of `Model.SiteSearchResults`?

Comment: It has to be a variable as any other type breaks the foreach. Is that the question?

Comment: You loop through your site search results but then you check if a checkbox is checked in Sitecore.Contex.Item instead of checking on the current loop item. I asked as the answer how to check if checkbox is checked depends on the type of the search results items.

Comment: Hey @MarekMusielak. Its a list of sitecore item ids. I was wondering if I had to do another loop to check the iteration of the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use extensions methods to make the method re-useable, but the key thing to take away from these solutions is utilising the utility function from Sitecore **MainUtil.GetBool(checkboxField.Value, false);**

```
using System;
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Data.Fields;
using Sitecore.Resources.Media;

namespace MyProject.Extensions
{
    public static class FieldExtensions
    {

        public static bool IsChecked(this Field checkboxField)
        {
            if (checkboxField == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(checkboxField));
            }
            return MainUtil.GetBool(checkboxField.Value, false);
        }
    }

    public static class ItemExtensions
    {
        public static bool IsChecked(this Item item, ID fieldId)
        {
            var checkboxField = item.Fields[fieldId];
            if (checkboxField == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(checkboxField));
            }
            return MainUtil.GetBool(checkboxField.Value, false);
        }
    }
}
```

**MyRendering.cshtml - using FieldExtensions**

```
@using MyProject.Extensions
@model Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel
@{

    var noIndexNoFollow = Model.Item.Fields["NoIndexNoFollow"].IsChecked();
}
```

**MyRendering.cshtml - using ItemExtensions**

```
@using MyProject.Extensions
@using Sitecore.Mvc
@model Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel
@{
    var noIndexNoFollow = Model.Item.IsChecked(Model.Item.Fields["NoIndexNoFollow"].ID);
}
```

Comment: Hey @nologo. I am trying to do this all within a cshtml file. Not sure if I want be calling from a cs file. Unless you think that is the only option I have.

Comment: @ImSobesBoosted i've updated my answer - this should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you wrote that `Model.SiteSearchResults` is a list of Sitecore `ID`.

You need to get item with this ID first and then check the value of the field using for example `MainUtil.GetBool()` method like:

```
foreach (var id in Model.SiteSearchResults)
{
    if (Sitecore.MainUtil.GetBool(Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(id)["NoIndexNoFollow"], false))
    {
        <text>checked</text>
    }
    else
    {
        <text>not checked</text>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var item in Model.SiteSearchResults)
{ 
Database database = Sitecore.Context.Database;
Item myItem = database.GetItem(item.ItemId);
var fieldValue = myItem.Fields["NoIndexNoFollow"];
string noIndexValue = Convert.ToString(fieldValue);
}
```

So after thinking more about what you guys said, I came up with a little easier solution that works perfect for what I need. I really appreciate all the insights!

Comment: you are doing this in the view rendering?!